# Can I share HBO Now or Netflix while using iCloud Family Sharing?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, sharing, netflix

If two people use the same Apple ID for logging into "iTunes & App Store" on iOS, then they can share app purchases, including the purchase of in-app subscriptions like HBO Now (or Netflix).

If two people use separate Apple IDs for logging into "iTunes & App Store", but link the Apple IDs via iCloud Family Sharing, then they can still share app purchases. However, they cannot share in-app purchases.

HBO Now (and Netflix) are in-app subscription purchases. So does this mean that, if I use iCloud Family Sharing, there is be no way to share a single subscription to HBO Now so that it can be used by everyone in my family?

Is there a way around this, that allows the family to use iCloud Family Sharing but still allows everyone to be able to use HBO now from their devices?

Answer (score 1):

HBO-Now and Netflix are Internet services.

Once you have a account you can log in from everywhere and from any device that supports it. You do not have to be in the same geographical location to share.

[image: does anyone read this]

No need for Apple ID, iCloud.

The maximum number of simultaneous connections is 3 for Netflix and HBO. If you need more connections (sharing) you can get it for small fee.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still a bit puzzled. Let's take HBO Now for example. If I subscribe to HBO Now via the iTunes Store using the HBO Now app (not using the HBO now website), then I am authorizing the payment using my AppleID/password, which I used to login to the iTunes Store. But someone else, say my wife, will be using a different AppleID on her device, so how can she use the subcription. Does the HBO Now app generate a separate user/pass pair, that we can share?

Comment: Ah, looks like it does... So you can pay for a subscription with an AppleID, but your HBO now subscription identity is separate from the payment identity...